# Remove \thechapter in the Introduction

Tags: sectioning, classicthesis, scrbook, ifthenelse

I'm using classicthesis with scrbook class, and my headings are defined as follows:

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\thesection}} \spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\lehead{\mbox{\llap{\small\thepage\kern1em\color{CTsemi}\vline}\hspace{0.5em}\color{CTsemi}
    \textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\thechapter}}\hspace{0.5em}
\headmark\hfil}}
\rohead{\mbox{\hfil{\color{CTsemi}\headmark\hspace{0.5em}}\rlap{\small{\color{CTsemi}\vline}\kern1em\thepage}}}
```

If I have no section, the right headings show the chapter title with no section numbering. However, in the introduction (\chapter*{Introduction}) In the left side i got this

\thepage | 0 Introduction

I'm reading about the \ifelse, but I don't get a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: It is hard to help you without a minimal reproducible example... https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You could try replacing `\thechapter` with `\leftmark`.